# Why Cocoa Touch umbrella header is not automatically generated based on framework public headers?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Let's have standard Cocoa framework with some objective-c classes with enabled modules. All headers marked public are available to outer application with `#import <Framework/PublicHeader.h>`.

Umbrella header is designed to simplify imports from framework. If this public header is not included in umbrella, Xcode show warning like 'Umbrella header does not include PublicHeader.h' and class isn't available through `@import Framework`.

So, when new public class is created, to be available to outer application through module, should be done both:

1. Moving this new header to framework public headers
2. Adding `#import <Framework/NewPublicHeader.h>` to umbrella with standard module map or in case of using custom module map adding `header "NewPublicHeader.h"` to it

Why umbrella header for framework is not automatically generated based on public headers and developers must do both 1 and 2 instead of only 1?
Is there any way to make it automatic (custom run script generated and copied umbrella to build folder introduces glitches with Xcode symbols indexing and code formatting, framework is in same workspace)?